# gmap3 Display cluster image on top of marker

Tags: google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I have used cluster and markers both. Cluster for workplaces and marker for users. Here User's marker should appear on top of cluster but i want on top cluster image and below user's marker. I have also try change in css like below-

```
.cluster-3
{
    background: url(images/m3.png) no-repeat;
    line-height: 66px;
    width: 70px;
    height: 56px;
    z-index:5000 !important;
    position:relative;   
}
```

But no effect on map.

Please suggest any good solution...

Answer (score 0):

There is `zIndex` property of [**MarkerOptions**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions),which you could modify to get desired effect.